# SELECT TOP 2 * table ORDER BY country

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Why am i getting more then 2 results, when i use
the statement?

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Customers ORDER BY Country DESC
```

you can try it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1

Comment: You should be getting no results, just an error.  MySQL does not support `top`.

Comment: limit used in MySQL, top is not valid at all in MySQL.... select top in SQL Server

Comment: The reason you are getting more than 2 results -- in all likelihood -- is because you are using MS Access.  Switch to SQL Server or use MySQL with `limit`, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Think he means he is getting more than 2 at w3schools. If you take his statement and run it at the link he provided, w3schools does return 4 rows.

Comment: @PCPGMR I only get 2 rows at that link?

Comment: @PCPGMR I got only 2 rows too

Comment: @PCPGMR I too got only 2 rows

Comment: i have removed the mysql tag. it was misleading.

at the link you have to add "order by country"
then you get 4 results.

Comment: I used 3 different ways, when using with desc gives you 4, without desc gives you 3, without order by gives you 2 results, must be a bug in the site!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL, then you're not using the proper syntax. You don't use `TOP`... that's for SQL Server (and other "Microsoftish" dialects ;-) ). You must use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY country DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: i have removed the mysql-tag. it was misleading.
my question is aiming to the results i get in
the w3schools link, when i add "order by country" to the statement.
as schown in my question.

Comment: ... but yes, i have tried your statement in mysql - no problems there.

thx for your help.

Comment: @thebiz One of the criticisms to SQL is that every vendor can implement his own "dialect", so porting is frequently a big headache.

Comment: OK, i see. I have just used ww3.schools SQL, to test a few things. Actually i am using mySQL as many guessed. Thanks for your interesting information.